# Postgres Get column name and value as rows for given ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (
 city_id int not null PRIMARY KEY,
 logdate date not null,
 peaktemp int,
 unitsales int
)
```

I need to get values for a given ID like this

```
select * from measurement where city_id ='1';

Name     |Value
---------|----------
city_id  |1
logdate  |2006-02-02
peaktemp |1
unitsales|1
```

is There any simple way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried pivot?

Comment: @Atk I have not tried. Can you help me

Comment: I can help you in sql server, but if you want it in postgresql then I would not be able to help.

Comment: In `psql`you can simply use `\x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the row to a json & then use json_each to transpose the data as you desire:

```
SELECT
  kv.key
, kv.value

FROM measurement 
   , json_each(row_to_json(measurement.*)) kv

WHERE city_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not looking for json representation. I am looking for as is representation for like arrays etc. Can this be modified?

Comment: @Patan: did you even run that statement? it does **not** output JSON. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I ran it. For array columns its gives representation as ["a"] where as in db actually it is {"a"}

Comment: Shrug. So arrays are displayed slightly differently. So what? That's only a different way of displaying the data for easier reading, why do you care?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Later I am planning to update the same table using key as column name and values. I am planning to implement all of this to happen dynamically.

Comment: Then you should have put _that_ into your question. But I don't how UPDATING the table is influenced by the way you display it.